# When I edit a keyframe the whole armature gets warped

Tags: keyframes

When I edit a keyframe the whole armature gets warped. This image below shows an armature that's unparented from its path curve. It looks pretty nice so I save it to keyframe 13 by pressing "i".

[image: before warped]

But when I scrub the dope sheet cursor away I get a warped image, even when I move the cursor back to keyframe 13. Please help me if you can.... I feel so lost after having studied this software for months.

[image]

I should say that the fixes I made were to align the eyeballs, teeth and hair with the head because they got disconnected somehow when I was making a walk cycle. I believe I have to do this for each key frame. The armature I'm working with had bones askew from the moment I imported it into my project. That's another problem. I can't even see the bones, just lines and circles that act as bones.

Through trial and error I pressed "shift" + "Ctrl" + "alt" + "C" together and I selected "origin to geometry". That got all the bone stick and circle thingies central to their respective body parts. But when I alter the sticks that control the eyes, nothing happens. They got disconnected from the armature. Funny thing is the eyes, teeth and hair are disconnected because when the armature tilts to and fro during the walk cycle they stay in the same place.

[image]

I now see that if I will correct this problem I will have to control the eyes, teeth and hair through their respective stick thingies and not by directly moving those parts through the mesh as I have tried in the beginning.

An update here.... the blue, concave band should move the teeth but when I move the gizmo the teeth don't move. Maybe I have to connect this band to the teeth somehow.

[image]

I clicked on the hair and and shift right clicked on the halo that should control it. Then I hit control P and selected the "Set Parent to object 
(keep transform) option. I then moved the hair indirectly by moving the halo and saved the keyframe by pressing "i". When I moved the cursor in the action container and put it back on that keyframe I got the same whacked out result.

[image]

You can see I'm doing my best, but any help from anyone would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Found out what I did to get such a messy and broken armature. I changed the origin position to the 3D cursor. Since everything was so askew, I just copied my dope sheet to an old saved version and started there. Thanks so much for the follow up